# Rails mailboxer notification relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, relation, mailboxer

I'm trying to do the relation:

```
has_many :notifications, foreign_key: :notified_object_id, conditions: {notified_object_type: 'AppShare'}, dependent: :destroy
```

found on this page: http://blog.meldium.com/home/2013/4/22/dont-spam-your-users-batch-notifications-in-rails

I have changed it to:

```
has_many :notifications, -> { where( notified_object_type: 'Assigment') }, foreign_key: "notified_object_id", dependent: :destroy
```

Because of the rails 4 syntax, but i'm getting this:

> uninitialized constant Assigment::Notification

can someone help me out here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are seeing similar error, I had to add `class_name: "Mailboxer::Notification"` to that `has_many` relation.

```
has_many :notifications, -> { where( notified_object_type: 'Assignment') },
    foreign_key: "notified_object_id", dependent: :destroy,
    class_name: "Mailboxer::Notification"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it just be the typo you've made on 'Assignment'? (You've spelled it 'Assigment', no N.)